# How often does FIDE review clocks to update their approved list?

Tags: fide, chess-clocks

The approved list seems to be rather old:
5.5. The electronic chess clocks endorsed by the FIDE
5.5.1. DGT XL (year 2007)
5.5.2. DGT 2010 (year 2010)
5.5.3. Silver Timer (year 2007)
5.5.4. Sistemco (year 2009)
5.5.5. DGT 3000 (year 2014)
5.5.6. CE Clock (year 2017)
5.5.7. KK9908 Clock (year 2017)

How often does FIDE review what clocks are available.  The only ones on that list that I might consider are very old now.  There are many better ones available. When will FIDE update that list?

Comment: some stalker is following me and downvoting everything they can.  I have to feel sorry for cowards and bullies like that.   The question is perfectly legit by stacks standards and they offer nothing about how to improve the question.

Comment: I am not always a fan of your answers (but I have still only downvoted you once...I rarely downvote anyone), but I call them as I see them, and there is nothing wrong with this question, so I just upvoted it.

Comment: I trust you to be fair.  However many others that are anonymous have proven to be less than honorable and fair.  It is clear that there is at least one cowardly stalker that follow me around and downvotes everything they can.

Answer (score 3):

They seem to have just finished the process literally YESTERDAY, but the new clocks have not made it into that list.

You would think that there would be a set of criteria that a company would have to meet, and if met, then they would get approval, but it appears to be more of a "money thing" than a "this-clock-is-good" thing.

I remembered looking for that when I was buying my clock, and they appear to do it as a bidding process, in other words, the companies pay for the right; and if they pay enough, they are approved.

https://www.fide.com/news/77

https://www.fide.com/news/346 (Note the date: Friday, 31 Jan 2020)

Comment: I would expect nothing less from FIDE.  It is a shame that the other group did not establish a foothold or better yet replace FIDE.

Comment: Your are confusing FIDE's sale of certain clock related marketing rights with the list of clocks which meet FIDE's technical specifications which FIDE publishes separately.